# Jest Issue with mocking api call and checking error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

I am using jest and trying to test an asynchronous login request. I am able to check that the call has resolved and is successful. I would also like to test the case that the call wasn't successful.

I have been following the [docs from here](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/tutorial-async).

I understand I am not doing the `reject` correctly, but if I move the `jest.mock('.utils/api', () => {...` into the test block it doesn't work, it needs to be outside. Can anyone advise the correct way to do this?

See my code below:

```
import React from 'react';
import { render, fireEvent } from 'react-testing-library';
import Login from './index';
import { login as mockLogin } from './api';

let mockData = {
    token: '12345'
};

let errorData = {
   message: 'Your username/password is incorrect'
};

jest.mock('.utils/api', () => {
    return {
        jsonRequest: jest.fn(() => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            resolve(mockData,);
            // I am not doing this correctly.
            reject(errorData);
        })),
    };
});


describe('<Login />', () => {   

    it('returns a sessionId if successful and error if not', () => {

        const { getByLabelText, getByText } = render(<Login />);
        const loginButton = getByText(/login/i);
        fireEvent.click(loginButton);
        expect(mockLogin).toBeCalledTimes(1);
        expect(mockLogin).toHaveBeenCalledWith('/login', {
            data: {
                password: 'test',
                username: 'test',
            },
            method: 'POST',
        });

        expect(mockLogin()).resolves.toBe(mockData);
        expect(mockLogin()).rejects(mockData);
    });
});
```

Comment: does anyone in SO land know how to do this :-D

Comment: how does your `mockLogin` gets called?

Comment: sorry, updated the question, it is called when `fireEvent.click(loginButton);`

Comment: @Abkreno does this help?

Comment: Yes it does however before you fire the login event you should make sure that the form is populated with the mocked data, after that you should test the scenario i mentioned in the answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to test here is the behavour of your component when the API rejects the request for some reason.

Assume this scenario:

Lets say the reason for rejection is that the **"Entered password is not correct"**. 
Then you need to make sure that the `Login` component will show an error message to the DOM where the user can see it and re-enter his password

To test this you need to make a check inside the mocked API, something like:

```
jsonRequest: jest.fn((formDataSubmittedFromComponent) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // Notice that the mocked function will recieve the same arguments that the real function recieves from the Login component
    // so you can check on these arguments here
   if (formDataSubmittedFromComponent.password !== mockData.password) {
     reject('Entered password is not correct') // << this is an error that your component will get and should handle it
   }
  resolve();

})),
```

After that you should test how did your component handle the reject

For example, you could test whether or not it displayed an error message to the DOM:

```
const errorMessageNode = getByTestId('error-message');
expect(errorMessageNode).toBeTruthy()
```

***Edit:*** before you fire the login event you should make sure that the form is populated with the mocked data

Comment: oh nice! this makes sense. I actually do collect all this data, but just left it out of the question

Comment: Ok great then, but you still need to reject the request somehow in the mocked API function hence do the check on the arguments passed from the Login component

Comment: yeah, makes sense